# Add two lists onto another list which

Tags: python-3.x

So I have two lists right now.

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

How can I merge the lists together to make it look something like this:

```
list3 = [['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3], ['D', 4]]
```

Basically I want to make a list inside a list.

I've been trying for loops but nothing seems to be working for me.

Comment: zip()..........

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

result = [list(i) for i in zip(list1,list2)]

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 1], ['B', 2], ['C', 3], ['D', 4]]
```